# Проблема с отображением на экране Android-устройства наследника View

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте. Пишу собственный виджет. Объект наследует View. Переопределил все необходимые методы. Объект принимает изображение при инициализации и показывает его в своих границах. 
Все работает, но вот в чем проблема. Вне зависимости от указания типа размещения в разметке, эти указания по запуску Activity, содержащей этот наследник View'а, просто игнорируются.
Поясню. При указанных для этого виджета в разметке свойствах:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Он все равно замощает весь экран по высоте, в то же время по задумке под этим виджетом располагается группа объектов (кнопки). Естественно кнопки скрыты виджетом.
В чем может быть проблема полного игнорирования разметки моим "custom" виджетом? Нужно дополнительно переопределить какие-то методы? Или я что-то мог упустить при задании самого виджета в разметке?

Все объекты помещены в <linearlayout></linearlayout>
Версия SDK - 1.5
IDE - Eclipse. Тестирую в эмуляторе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из документации:

> Implementing a Custom View
>
> To implement a custom view, you will usually begin by providing overrides for some of the standard methods that the framework calls on all views. You do not need to override all of these methods. In fact, you can start by just overriding onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas).

[дока](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Вообщем, посмотрите на методы:

- onMeasure(int, int)
- onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)
- onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)
- onDraw(Canvas)

Не все из них просто реализовать, поэтому советую найти и посмотреть исходники, например на Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, эти аттрибуты надо отрабатывать самостоятельно, раз вы перекрываете onMeasure?

Comment: onMeasure? Что за метод, его не переопределял. Видимо тут может крыться причина.

Comment: onMeasure определяет реальные размеры объекта. То есть для текст-бокса это будет рамка описывающая сам текст. Для других вьюшек не в курсе.